# System.Data.OracleClient and .Net Core 2: Additional symbol some times?

Tags: oracle, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

here is how to reproduce it:

1. Make new console .Net Core 2 project.
2. Add System.Data.OracleClient from NuGet.
3. Change the class Program with this:

   ```
   class Program  
   {  
       const string testSql = @"  
       SELECT  extension,  
            CASE UPPER (EXTENSION)  
                 WHEN 'DOC' THEN 'application/msword'  
                 WHEN 'DOCX' THEN 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'  
                 WHEN 'XLS' THEN 'application/vnd.ms-excel'  
                 WHEN 'XLSX' THEN 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'  
                 WHEN 'PPT' THEN 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint'  
                 WHEN 'PPTX' THEN 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation'  
                 WHEN 'EPS' THEN 'application/postscript'  
                 WHEN 'GIF' THEN 'image/gif'  
                 WHEN 'BMP' THEN 'image/bmp'  
                 WHEN 'JPG' THEN 'image/jpeg'  
                 WHEN 'MP4' THEN 'video/mp4'  
                 WHEN 'PDF' THEN 'application/pdf'  
                 WHEN 'PNG' THEN 'image/png'  
                 WHEN 'PSD' THEN 'image/vnd.adobe.photoshop'  
                 WHEN 'TIF' THEN 'image/tiff'  
                 WHEN 'TIFF' THEN 'image/tiff'  
                 WHEN 'ZIP' THEN 'application/zip'  
                 ELSE 'text/plain'  
              END AS mime_type  
         FROM (  
            select 'bmp' as extension from dual  
            union all  
            select 'jpg' as extension from dual  
            union all  
            select 'tif' as extension from dual  
            union all  
            select 'pdf' as extension from dual  
            union all  
            select 'zip' as extension from dual  
            union all  
            select 'gif' as extension from dual  
            union all  
            select 'txt' as extension from dual  
         )";  

       const string _connString = "Data Source = mydatabase; User Id = myuser; Password=mypw;Min Pool Size=1;";  

       static void Main(string[] args)  
       {  
           using (var myconn = new OracleConnection(_connString))  
           {  
               myconn.Open();  
               OracleCommand oc = new OracleCommand(testSql, myconn);  
               using (OracleDataReader odr = oc.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.Default))  
               {  
                   while (odr.Read())  
                   {  
                       var s = odr.GetString(odr.GetOrdinal("MIME_TYPE"));  
                       Console.WriteLine($"Extension: {odr[0]}  Mime type: {odr[1]}");  
                   }  
               }  
               Console.ReadKey();  
           }  
       }  
   }
   ```
4. Change the DB, User and Password and start the program.

What I get is this:

```
Extension: bmp  Mime type: image/bmp?
Extension: jpg  Mime type: image/jpeg?
Extension: tif  Mime type: image/tiff?
Extension: pdf  Mime type: application/pdf
Extension: zip  Mime type: application/zip
Extension: gif  Mime type: image/gif?
Extension: txt  Mime type: text/plain?
```

Look at the '?' at the end of some rows.
The question is: Is this an error on my Oracle Client or is in the System.Data.OracleClient?

Comment: Namespace `System.Data.OracleClient` is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-and-adonet) for ages. You should not use it. Do you get the same problem when you use the Oracle provider which is supported and further developed?

Comment: @Wernfried There is no Oracle provider for .Net Core 2. We are waiting Oracle to make it. Why is ported to .Net Standard, when is deprecated?

Comment: I don't know, ask Microsoft why they stopped development. There seems to be some hope for the Managed Driver: [Statement of Direction: ODP.NET on Microsoft .NET Core](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/tech-info/odpnet-dotnet-core-sod-3628981.pdf)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I do not ask, why they stopped development, but why they ported it to .Net Standard, when is deprecated. When is ported should at least work. And about Oracle, I remember that we have waited 3 years for ODP.Net. And now is only 1.5 years since we wait for .Net Core version. They have still time.

Answer (score 2):

We faced the same problem. This is a problem in system.data.oracleclient. So we have used this unofficial library based on System.Data.OracleClient mono project: https://github.com/ericmend/oracleClientCore-2.0 
This does solve the problem of additional symbols but System.Data.Oracleclient is very slow to read large data as it has been deprecated long ago but until oracle releases official client for .net core this can be used for small data sets.

Please see this similar post which helped us: [.NET Core 2 + System.Data.OracleClient. Chinese characters doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46075135/net-core-2-system-data-oracleclient-chinese-characters-doesnt-work/47960980#47960980)

Comment: I've came to this conclusion because i've tested it and it does solve the problem asked in this question. Not sure why the downvote. I've updated few words in my answer to be more clear.