# Odp.net DLL Issue in .net core app2 web application

Tags: .net

I am trying to use odp.net DLL(Oracle.Dataaccess.dll & Oracle.ManagedDataaccess) in asp.net core app to but it is giving dependencies warning as Oracle.dataaccess is trying to restore using .net framework 4.6.1 instead of .net core app2 I have tried with targeting multiple frame works also but issue was not resolved.

Comment: Please include both the code and the exact error that code is giving.

Comment: It's not related to code issue related to DLL issue

Comment: Odp.net DLL is not working to connect to Oracle database in asp.net core2 app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle hasn't released managed client for .net core yet.So ODP.net that you are trying to use won't work with core. Until Oracle release official client you can use this unofficial library based on System.Data.OracleClient mono project: https://github.com/ericmend/oracleClientCore-2.0
Although it is very slow to read large data. Please see this post for known bugs and fixes: [.NET Core 2 + System.Data.OracleClient. Chinese characters doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46075135/net-core-2-system-data-oracleclient-chinese-characters-doesnt-work/47960980#47960980)